# I keep getting errors python 2.7

Tags: python

I am getting an error on line 14? I am new to python, very new, started 3 days ago.

```
varA = 2
varB = 1

if varB or varA == str:
 print("string involved")

elif varA > varB:
 print('bigger') 

elif varA == varB:
 print('equal')

else varA < varB:  
 print('smaller')  # this is line 14, why am I getting an error here?
```

Comment: [`else` clause](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#else) does not take predicate. Replace `else varA < varB:` with `else:`.

Comment: In the future, when you get an error, please post the error message (the whole thing, with the traceback) so we don't have to to guess. This time it was easy enough (and falsetru is fast enough) that it didn't waste any time, but in general it will.

Comment: It would be useful in future to indicate what kind of errors you get and/or to mark out the line where you got the error. 14 is still easy to count, if it had been 67 or 80 that might have been a different story.

Keep working :)

Comment: @falsetru: You should post that as an answer, since that's about all there is to say.

Comment: @abarnert Oh but that's [not all there is to say](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19580077/418413).

Comment: if type(varA) == str or type(varB) == str:

would have been better ?

Answer (score 9):

You must change the second-last line to

```
elif varA < varB:
```

or to

```
else:
```

`else` cannot be used with a condition.

By the way: Your first `if` probably does not do what you want it to do.  The condition you wrote evaluates to `(varB) or (varA == str)`. What you want to do is:

```
if isinstance(varA, basestring) or isinstance(varB, basestring):
```

Comment: what about if varB == str or varA == str:

Comment: The logic is better. But it will not do what you want it to do. `str` is a class. So if you compare `var` with `str`, it will only be equal if `var` is a reference to the `str` class. (You can try it using the interactive interpreter.) My code checks whether `var` is a string instance.